# VueJS - Load child components dynamically

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I'm trying to figure out how to conditionally load sub/child component from Laravel's blade template

1. I have a main container, which is being called from the blade:

   `<structure-container view='menu-index'></structure-container>`
2. Here is the StructureContainer.vue

   ```
   <template>
   <div>
       //I can have if-else statement here by "view", but looking for a better solution
       <menu-index></menu-index>
   </div>
   ```

   ```
   export default{
       components: {
           'menu-index': require('./menu/IndexComponent.vue'),
           'test': require('./menu/TestComponent.vue'),
       },
       props: ['view']
   }
   ```

As you can see I have two child components: menu-index & test. I want to pass the parameter from blade and display the corresponding component. Can I avoid if-else statements? there should be a better way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply bind the component name dynamically to the `is` property (using `v-bind:is` or `:is`), i.e.:

```
<div>
    <component :is="view"></component >
</div>
```

The really awesome thing about this is that the `<component>` container is reactive, and you can dynamically load/unload/change the components on-the-fly. How awesome is that? :)

For more information, I encourage you to read up the [documentation on dynamic components on the official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

Comment: Thanks Terry, makes sense. It also works if directly bound to the props "view"
`<component :is="view"></component >`

Comment: @GeorgeSharvadze Glad it worked. Yes, that will also work if you bind it to the prop directly. I will update my answer to reflect that ;)