# Dynamically show components depending on the current route, vuejs

Tags: vue.js

In vue how do I dynamically show components based on the current route?

I only want the `custom-component`to be visible if not on the homepage. And by default, I set that the user is on the homepage so the component doesn't show on load.

I've tried several router methods with no luck: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-instance-methods.

app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :class="$style.app">
    <navbar/>
    <custom-component v-bind:is="homePage"></custom-component>
    <router-view :class="$style.content"/>
    <footer/>
  </div>
</template>


  data() {
    return {
      homePage: true
    }
  },
 methods: {
     homePage() {
  if(this.$route.path("/") || this.$route.path("/home")) {
    this.homePage = true
  } else {
    this.homePage = false
  }
}
}
```

This is close, but doesn't achieve the desired results: [VueJS - Load child components dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45613935/vuejs-load-child-components-dynamically).

Also would this be the best way to do it in `app.vue` as I am trying now. Or should I have this logic in the `custom-component` instead?

Answer (score 7):

Why not using a computed property instead of a method ?

```
export default {
    computed: {
      homePage() {
        if(this.$route.path == "/" || this.$route.path == "/home" ) {
          return true
        } else {
          return false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve your goal by using `v-if` or `v-show` directives

```
<custom-component v-show="homePage"></custom-component>
```

Or

```
<custom-component v-if="homePage"></custom-component>
```

If i were you i would watch the route object for further changes like [this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes) and use one of the option above according to this statement

> Generally speaking, v-if has higher toggle costs while v-show has
> higher initial render costs. So prefer v-show if you need to toggle
> something very often, and prefer v-if if the condition is unlikely to
> change at runtime.

You can check out further details about conditional rendering from vue.js [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

> Also would this be the best way to do it in app.vue as I am trying
> now.

No, you shouldn't bloat your app.vue file whilst you can handle the same
problem with different components in more modular way.

> Or should I have this logic in the custom-component instead?

In general if you can assume that this chunk of code can be used in different parts of the application, it's better to implement as different component.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option to show some component on the page is a method that return true or false. When we use v-if, component will be ignored during rendering.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app" :class="$style.app">
    <navbar/>
    <custom-component v-if="homePage()"></custom-component>
    <router-view :class="$style.content"/>
    <footer/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      homePage() {
        if(this.$route.path == "/" || this.$route.path == "/home" ) {
          return true
        } else {
          return false
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: you can simply rewrite the `hompage` function to be like this: `homePage() { return this.$route.path == "/" || this.$route.path == "/home" }`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `v-if` binding in your component

```
<custom-component v-if="homePage" v-bind:is="homePage"></custom-component>
```

where homePage is a bool value.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The `v-if` works as it should. The issue remains that I am unable to get the component to only show on every page, but the homepage. None of the router instance methods have helped.